# How to Optimize VAR model in python?

Tags: python, time-series, var, statsmodels, forecasting

I'm currently using VAR model for MTS[multivariate time-series] forecasting on monthly sales dataset with MAPE as 19.08. Please find my data distribution below.

**TRAIN:** 36 months
**TEST:**  12 months
**MAPE:**  19.08

I would like to optimize the model further and I tried almost of various `lag/order[differentiation]` combinations based on Min AIC score & Min MAPE Score,

```
approach: diff, order: 1, lag: 1, MAPE: 28.07, AIC: 41.3  
approach: diff, order: 1, lag: 2, MAPE: 35.07, AIC: 32.89  
approach: diff, order: 1, lag: 3, MAPE: 35.60, AIC: -270.1  
approach: log, order: 0, lag: 1, MAPE: 24.27, AIC: -94.28  
approach: log, order: 0, lag: 2, MAPE: 31.32, AIC: -130.50  
approach: log, order: 0, lag: 3, MAPE: 21.02, AIC: 14.02  
approach: log-diff, order: 1, lag: 1, MAPE: 25.31, AIC: -491.07  
approach: log-diff, order: 1, lag: 2, MAPE: 24.31, AIC: -498.85  
approach: log-diff, order: 1, lag: 3, MAPE: 24.68, AIC: -489.60
```

I would like to know more about further optimization techniques or tips on the VAR model. Any kind of suggestions relates to performance improvement are welcome.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Hi @ppwater, I tried building model for various combinations of differencing/Transformation techniques with multiple lag order form range (1, 15) like below.

approach: diff, order: 1, lag: 1  
approach: diff, order: 1, lag: 2  
approach: diff, order: 1, lag: 3  
approach: log, order: 1, lag: 1  
approach: log, order: 1, lag: 2  
approach: log, order: 1, lag: 3  
approach: log-diff, order: 1, lag: 1  
approach: log-diff, order: 1, lag: 2  
approach: log-diff, order: 1, lag: 3   
and so on each gives me different output with different mape score

Comment: Ah, okay. please [edit] your question with that.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you can try:

1. Rather than taking all independent variables. Try causality test and correlation, and use only variables which seems to make more effect on target variable.
2. Try applying PCA on similar kind of independent variable ,rather than dropping columns.